# Windows Wpf how can I dynamically create xaml grid using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, foreach

Using Visual Studio 2019 + Resharper.

hey guys, i want to add listviews, that show things from objects, which i get from a list.
it looks like this, when i code it manually:

The XAML-Code:

```
 <ListView Margin="43,313,642,29" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" x:Name="Module1">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Modul"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </WrapPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

and the c# code:

```
            List<Module> somename = pPP_2.Components.Modules.Values.Cast<Module>().ToList();

            List<Module> whatevername = new List<Module>(){somename[0]};

            Module1.ItemsSource = whatevername;
```

The Modules i refer to have several properties, and the `{somename[0]}` just gets the first of them and puts it in the list.

So basically my question:
How can i create such xaml code using c#? I want to create a listview like this for each element in my list. i Don´t want to create them manually but let the code do it for me.

thinking about this for days now and would love to get some help here.

Thanks,
IRezzet.

P.S. You can basically ignore the special list i created there. The question should work for every List.

Comment: Why don't you create a user control containing the ListView and a (dependency) property for the items source? The you simply add a new instance of your control with new List<Module> list as parameter?

Comment: Your code won't do it for you as you need to create it! Also, look into `DataTemplates` which you are already using, these will actually be used for your items lists, etc ... Using xaml is much easier than using code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `ItemsControl` with a `ItemTemplate` that renders a `ListView` that has an `ItemTemplate` rendering the listview-items. If this gets too complex, consider seperating this into a usercontrol to make it more generic.

The XAML would look something like this:

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="DynamicGrid">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListView BorderThickness="2" ItemsSource="{Binding SubChildren}" BorderBrush="Red">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

You will need two Model types for this

```
    // And an instance variable
    public ObservableCollection<Outer> Lists { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Outer>();
    public class Outer
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Inner> SubChildren { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Inner>();
    }
    public class Inner
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I used this code to seed for testing:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var o = new Outer();
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            {
                o.SubChildren.Add(new Inner() { Name = "ID: "+k });
            }
            Lists.Add(o);
        }
        DynamicGrid.ItemsSource = Lists;
```